# The difference between react-redux and redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm following a tutorial for building a full stack React E-commerce site, and after finishing the UI and the backend, the presenter said that we will work now with Redux, and in console he installed two redux packages with `npm install @reduxjs/toolkit react-redux`.

My question is what is the difference between `react-redux` and `redux-toolkit` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The react redux package provides the bindings for react (useSelector, useDispatch, etc)

The redux toolkit package is a 'friendly interface' for redux. Definetly go for the toolkit package instead of vanilla redux :)

P.S. the toolkit package provides an out of the box 'object immutability feature' using immer

Answer (score 1):

`Redux toolkit` has usage while you are debugging your code using `Redux DevTools` . `React-redux` has some React hooks and useful methods for working with Redux in React for exp : `useSelector` , `useDispatch` and ...